# How to restrict user by entering data for specific month where records greater than secific month exists in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am using Yii2 basic. I have a table called groupsavingdetails which stores the monthly saving for each groups.

Suppose I have a group whose date of formation is 2017-08-08. Now while creating monthly saving records for this group I will select the group enter year as 2017 and month as August and enter all the values which will give me the closing balance for August and save in database.

Now when the user wants to make entry for October instead of september month he can do it as the system will show the August closing balance as opening balance and he will do the same for october month as done for august.

***Now after making entry for october the user must not be able to enter record for september month.***

I have records for this group for year 2017 and from months August, September, October, November and December.

What happens is that When I enter year as 2018 and month as January then alert message is displayed, which should not be displayed.

***Here the condition is getting failed while saving the record.***

```php
$group = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT *
    FROM groupsavingdetails
    where groupsavingdetails.GroupId=:id
    ORDER BY groupsavingdetails.GroupSavingDetailsId DESC LIMIT 1')
->bindValues([
    ':id' => $model->GroupId,
])->queryAll();


$year2=0;
$month3=0;
foreach($group as $groups) {
    $model->OpeningBalance=$groups['ClosingBalance'];
    $model->TotalValueofLoanGiven=$groups['TotalValueofLoanGiven'];
    $model->LoanRepaidUptilNow=$groups['LoanRepaidUptilNow'];
    $model->TotalValueOfLoanOutstanding=$groups['TotalValueOfLoanOutstanding'];
    $year2=$groups['Year'];
    $month3=$groups['Month'];
}

$identity = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
$eid = $identity->id;
$model->EmpId = $eid;

if($model->LoanGiven!=0) {
    $model->TotalValueofLoanGiven+=$model->LoanGiven;
}

if($model->LoanRecovery!=0) {
    $model->LoanRepaidUptilNow+=$model->LoanRecovery;
}

$model->TotalValueOfLoanOutstanding = $model->TotalValueofLoanGiven-$model->LoanRepaidUptilNow;

$previousMonth = $model->Month - 1;
if ($previousMonth == 0) {
    $previousMonth = 12;
    $year2--;
}

// Here the condition is getting failed.
if ($model->Year >= $year2 && $model->Month > $previousMonth) {
    $model->ClosingBalance=($model->OpeningBalance+$model->TotalSaving+$model->LoanRecovery+$model->LoanInterest+$model->Fine+$model->BankInterest+$model->BankLoan-$model->Expenses-$model->LoanGiven);
    $model->save(); 
} else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Records greater than selected year and month exists.')";
    echo "</script>";

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your condition

```php
$model->Year >= $year2 && $model->Month > $previousMonth
```

In your condition there are two expressions joined with **and** (`&&`). That means that both expressions must be true for the whole condtion to be true.

Lets have `$year2 = 2017` and `$previousMonth = 10` (october).

Now you set the $model->Year to 2018 and $model->Month = 1 (january).
The first expression in condtion is `2018 >= 2017`. This part is `true`. But the second expression is `1 > 10` which is`false`. Then `true && false` will result in `false`.

What you  actually need to do is to check the month only when the year is same. So the condition you are looking for is:

```php
$model->Year > $year2 || ($model->Year == $year2 && $model->Month > $previousMonth)
```

This condition will work like this:

```
Year = 2018
Month = 1

2018 > 2017 || (2018 == 2017 && 1 > 10)
true || (false && false)
true || false
true
```

```
Year = 2017
Month = 11

2017 > 2017 || (2017 == 2017 && 11 > 10)
false || (true && true)
false || true
true
```

```
Year = 2017
Month = 9

2017 > 2017 || (2017 == 2017 && 9 > 10)
false || (true && false)
false || false
false
```

Comment: It works when year is 2018 and month is January. After this I enter record for Year 2018 and month March instead of February. It also works. But after that when I try to enter for year 2018 and month February, still the record gets saved. Here the alert is not showing

Comment: I see, i've missed how you are setting `$previousMonth`. Why exactly do you set it as `$model->Month - 1` instead of using `$month3` which is the month of latest record? Are you trying to allow creating records from october 2018 when there already are some records in year 2019 but none from  october/november/december 2018?

Comment: First I check if $model->Year==$year2, then inside it checks if $model->Month>$month3, then will perform calculation and saving in database else alert is shown. Similarly next if $model->Year>$year2, then inside it $month3=0 and check $model->Year>$month3, then calculate and save else alert is shown. It is working Thankyou